# jquery defer and asynchronous ajax requests. - race condition?

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I'm stuck trying to get my ajax requests to guarantee a response from my loaded templates.

Basically if I run my code to return my deferred object the $.then() calls before I have my template object. This only happens on the first run.

I'm tearing my hair out with this one!

My ajax call:

```
var ajax = {
    getTemplate: (function (id) {
    /// <summary>
    ///     This method when used with $.Deferred fetches a html string 
    ////    containing the template appliciable 
    ///     to the the supplied id.
    ///     The ajax request object is cached upon the first request and is
    ///     returned by the cache 
    ///     upon each subsequent request.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id" type="String">
    ///     The id that matches the filename to request the template object
    ///     from.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns type="jqXHR">
    ///      A superset of the XMLHTTPRequest object that impliments the
    ///      promise interface.
    /// </param>

    var cache = {}; // private cache

    // Gets assigned to getTemplate.
    return function (id) {

    var url = "/templates/" + id + ".tpl";
    return cache[id]|| $.ajax({
           url: url,
           dataType: "html",
           success: function (data) {

               //ajax.getTemplate(id, data);
               cache[id] = data;
           },
           error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               log("template request " + id, 
                   XMLHttpRequest, 
                   textStatus, 
                   errorThrown);
           }
           });
        };
    } ())
};
```

I'm calling this on in my method like this:

```
$.when(ajax.getTemplate("tooltip-attributes")()).then(function (template) {

    if (template) {
       // Do my template stuff here.
    }

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes like to wrap ajax calls with my own deferred because I don't want to expose the ajax deferred and instead just resolve it with some custom object based on whatever the ajax call returned. For example:

```
function myFunction(resolved) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    if ($.IsNullOrEmpty(resolved)) {
        deferred.reject("Parameters are required.");
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/something/somewhere",
            data: { someParameter : "someValue" },
            dataType: "json"
        }).done(function (result) {
            if (result.success === false) {
                deferred.reject({
                    success: false,
                    reason: "you fail"
                });
            } else {
                deferred.resolve({
                    success: true,
                    result: result.someData
                });
            }
        });
    }
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

Then I'll create another deferred promise to resolve it:

```
var deferred = $.Deferred(),
    promise = deferred.promise();

promise
    .then(myFunction)
    .then(someOtherDependentFunction)
    .fail(function (response) {
        // do fail stuff
    })
    .done(function () {
        // do done stuff
    });
```

You could use "when" here as well for async, instead of chaining them like that.

Then just resolve the thing

```
deferred.resolve({
    member: item
});
```

I like this because it allows me to build a dynamic function chain by making someOtherDependentFunction for example to be any other function that uses the resolved data and returns the promise. Obviously there are a lot of other ways one could use this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you aren't creating your Deferred correctly.

try changing the top function to

```
// Gets assigned to getTemplate.
return $.Deferred(function (id) {
```

Comment: Sorry - I didn't read your code completely enough - never come across jQuery deferred personally. See edit above.

Comment: As far as I've figured out The $.ajax function itself returns a deferred object with the success function mapping to the $Deferred().done(); Adding another deferred just seems to break the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/), especially the section "Defer your Deferreds". This documentation about the [jQuery.pipe()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/) function is interesting too!

Thing is that every function called within $.when() need to call its promise() function in order the $.when() to wait for the completion of each function. Apparently returning an object from cache does not resolve the deferred!

Start off by letting your function always return a $.Deferred object like BonyT already described AND let it call the promise() function:

```
getTemplate: (function(id) {
    return $.Deferred(function (id) {...}
    .promise();
})()
```

Your inner return provides either a cached object that is already existing OR a $.ajax xmlhttp request. The latter always returns a Deferred object calling the .resolve() function in its .done() callback handler function - but the cache version doesn't! So you have to manually call the $.Deferred.resolve() OR $.Deferred.reject() in case of extracting your data from the local cache object.

```
getTemplate: (function(id) {
    if (cache.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
        var dfd = $.Deferred();
        var filtered = dfd.pipe(function(value) {
            return cache[value];
        });
        return dfd.resolve(id);
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: "html"
        })
        .done(function(result) {
            /*fires when resolved*/
            return result;
        })
        .fail(/*fires only when rejected*/)
        .always(/*fires when both rejected or resolved*/);
    }
})()
```

By the way don't use .success() and .error() any more since they will be [deprecated in jQuery 1.8](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) "Deprecation notice". Use .done(), .fail() and .always() instead.

Answer (score 0):

Probably what's confusing you is having an outer `id` and an inner `id` ... neither of which gets assigned.

The outer `id` can actually disappear - it would only be assigned if you passed an id in the self-executor call.

Now, the actual fix is to call the inner function (the one returned by `ajax.getTemplate()`) properly :

```
$.when(ajax.getTemplate()("tooltip-attributes")).then(...);
```

Note that "tooltip-attributes" now appears in the *second* set of parentheses. But there's a good reason not to call it this way - namely that every `ajax.getTemplate()` call would have its own, independent cache, not one common cache. It would make more sense to do as follows :

```
var templateGetter = ajax.getTemplate();//Assign the returned function to make it reusable
...
$.when(templateGetter("tooltip-attributes")).then(...);
```

Personally, I find the whole construction confusing and would probably use a Crockford-style module pattern as follows:

```
var AJAX = {
    var cache = {}; // private cache of jqXHR objects (promises)
    var getTemplate = function (id) {
        var url = "/templates/" + id + ".tpl";
        if(!cache[id]) {
            cache[id] = $.ajax({
                url: url,
                dataType: 'html',
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    log("template request " + id, XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }
        return cache[id];
    };
    return {
        getTemplate: getTemplate
    }
};
```

Now, `AJAX.getTemplate()` is guaranteed to return a promise.

```
AJAX.getTemplate("tooltip-attributes").then(function (template) {
    if (template) {
        // Do my template stuff here.
    }
});
```

Comment: Waaaaaaah, I only just noticed how old this question is - over 3 and a half years!